# print all words of a dictionary using trie

Tags: c++, c, trie

I am working on a dictionary using a trie with the following struct in c

```
  struct trie_node {
    int is_end;   //0 is is not the end of the word ,otherwise 1
    char c;       
    struct trie_node* child[26];
  };
```

I am able to insert words, search words and I would like to print all the words of the dictionary. Not sure how to handle it. I was trying to print

```
void print(struct trie_node node) {
int i = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    if (node->child[i] != NULL) {
       printf("%c", node->child[i]->c);
       print(node->child[i]);
    }
 }
```

}

But it is not printing correctly
if for example I have the words
beer
bee
bear
beast

it is printing
bearster
it should print
bearbeastbeebeer

How can I print correctly the list of words ?

Comment: When you recursively call `print(node->child[i]);`, you're not printing any of the characters from the ancestor nodes. So after printing `bear`, your program is then printing the `st` at the end of `beast` without repeating the first three characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [algorithm to print trie alphabetically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843628/algorithm-to-print-trie-alphabetically)

Comment: You've not provided enough information for us to reproduce the issue you describe; try moving your *example* from *English* to *C* or *C++* (and make sure it compiles and runs, so we can reproduce the issue you describe)... The other thing is, you need to *pick a language*; either C or C++. If your code compiles with a C compiler, you can pick C. Otherwise, pick C++.

Comment: @zancudo, please look at my answer down below and let me know if you tried it out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of the path (path from the root to the current node). When you reach to an end node (is_end is true), you print the path which is the dictionary word.

One approach is to use an array of `char` and keep track of its length so you know how many of elements you need to print. See the code below:

```
void print_path (char *path, int len){
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    printf("%c", path[i]);
}
void print(struct trie_node* node, char *path, int len) {
  // sanity check
  if (! node)
    return;

  // current node is part of the current path, so add it
  path[len++] = node->c;

  // if it is an end node then print the path
  if (node->is_end)
    print_path(path, len);  

  // now go through the children and recursive call 
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    if (node->child[i] != NULL) {
      print(node->child[i], path, len);                     
    }
  }
}

int main(){
  // proper allocation for the trie
  // ...
  // calling the print, assuming the height of tree is at most 128
  char path[128];
  print(b, path, 0);
}
```

Comment: Also, I suggest that you [stop casting `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) or [stop using `malloc` in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new), think about `sizeof (char)` (both type-wise in retrospect of `int len` and value-wise in retrospect of `malloc(128 * 1)`) and when it might be most appropriate to use automatic storage duration as opposed to dynamic allocation (`malloc`/`free`, `new`/`delete`, whatever your choice)...

Comment: It always astounds me when people cast the return value of `malloc` but not the argument of `free`; that blows the entire reasoning for casting `malloc` out of the window. So you need the cast to convert a `void *` to a `char *` in C++, but you don't need it the other way around? Hmmm...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out (no casting needed with malloc).

Comment: At the end, I removed the malloc allocation since the allocation size is fixed.

Comment: Yes, you've chosen automatic storage duration... Good choice :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use node.child[i]->c,when use struct var you must use a ".",when use struct point must use "->" or "(&point).",i don't know my think is true : )